# How to save variables when replacing the fragment?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments

In my first fragment I have an `EditText` with a value. The problem is when I go to `FragmentTwo` and go back to `FragmentOne` the `EditText` (in `FragmentOne`) loses the text I previous inserted. I tried to save it in the `onSaveInstanceState()` and retrieve in the `onViewStateRestored()` but it seems that he does not store the information because the `onSaveInstanceState()` is never called and the `savedInstanceState` is always null.

This is my fragment replacing method

```
fragmentManager
                ?.beginTransaction()
                ?.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_left, R.anim.slide_out_right, R.anim.slide_in_right)
                ?.replace(frame, MyFragment.newInstance(), tag)
                ?.addToBackStack(tag)
                ?.commit()
```

This is my `onSaveInstanceState()` in `FragmentOne`:

```
 override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
        outState.putDouble(Constants.currentAmount, currentAmount)
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
    }
```

This is my onViewRestored in `FragmentOne`:

```
override fun onViewStateRestored(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewStateRestored(savedInstanceState)
        if(savedInstanceState!= null) {
            currentAmountSaved = savedInstanceState.getDouble(Constants.currentAmount)
        }
    }
```

This is my back press in `FragmentTwo`:

```
 fragmentManager?.popBackStack()
```

So my goal is to save the `EditText`, pass to `FragmentTwo`, and when I go back to `FragmentOne` the same `EditText` is with the value I put when I change `Fragments`.

This is my xml file from the `FragmentOne`(The fragment I want to restore)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/contentView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <View
        android:id="@+id/fManageFundsHeaderLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:background="@color/colorBackgroundToolbar"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/addFundsComponent"
        layout="@layout/component_manage_funds"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/fManageFundsHeaderLayout" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: So Dawid can you take a look at the problem?

Comment: Could you provide here your fragments `.xml` files?

Comment: Yes I will edit my question.

Comment: Hello please check https://github.com/Zhuinden/guide-to-kotlin/wiki/6.)-Anti-Patterns#unnecessary-chaining-of-safe-call-operator

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
private var contentView: View? = null

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    if (contentView == null) {
        contentView = inflater.inflate(xxxxx)
    }
    (contentView?.parent as? ViewGroup)?.removeView(contentView)
    return contentView
}
```

Comment: Does not solve my problem when I do an onBackPressed()

Answer (score -1):

I think that u r using wrong restore state callback. Try to explore Bundle object from onCreate/onCreateView methods of fragment

Comment: This is not a complete answer, please edit or post as a comment.  If you do not have enough reputation to add comments then try answering questions that you can provide complete solutions for.

Comment: @MarkKeen can you take a look and give your input at the problem.